# Why am I getting this 400 bad request?

Tags: apache-httpd, http, c++

I'm maintaining an old app in C++ that goes a http get request. However, the apache2 gives me a 400 error

Error log

> [22/Mar/2020:20:04:33 +0000] "GET
>   /hover/imr.php?=ADD_GAME%%16-0%%%43%6c%61%73%73%69%63%48%%%43%6c%61%73%73%69%63%48%%5%%x7f%%9530
>   HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"

Is there any way for me to diagnose what is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because for security reasons apache doesn't allow encoded slashes in a url. My solution will have to be replacing the slash with another answer.